# Assign value to new column if another column has exact string

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this.

```
Date    Winner
4/12    Tom
4/13    Abe
4/14    George
4/15    Tom
```

I would like to add new columns that assign a 1 if if the name appears in the winner column and 0 if the name did not appear and vice versa. Ideally the df would look like this as a result

```
Date    Winner    Tom_Win    Tom_Lose    Abe_Win    Abe_Lose    George_Win    George Lose    
4/12    Tom       1          0           0          1           0           1
4/13    Abe       0          1           1          0           0           1
4/14    George    0          1           0          1           1           0  
4/15    Tom       1          0           0          1           0           1
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: This worked perfectly! One of the many great answers I received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is extremely simple to do if you use the model.matrix functions, it will create N dummy columns with 0 when the name does not appear and one when it does (exactly as you requested), the code below: 
(assuming your data is called db)

```
> winners <- model.matrix(~Winner - 1, data=db)
> winners

  WinnerAbe WinnerGeorge WinnerTom
1         0            0         1
2         1            0         0
3         0            1         0
4         0            0         1
```

This bit is to compute the columns with the losing values

```
winners <- as.data.frame(winners)
winners$loserAbe <- as.numeric(!winners$WinnerAbe) #naturally you have to 
                                                   #do this for every column you need
  WinnerAbe WinnerGeorge WinnerTom loserAbe
1         0            0         1        1
2         1            0         0        0
3         0            1         0        1
4         0            0         1        1

winners$Date <- db$Date #this last bit so you don't lose the date.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! One of the many great answers I received

Answer (score 2):

Using `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` package we can do the following three steps,

```
library(qdapTools)

d1 <- mtabulate(d3$Winner)

d2 <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(d1, function(i) ifelse(i == 1, 0, 1))), 
                                                       paste0(names(d1), '_Lose'))

cbind(d3$Date, d1, d2)

#  d3$Date Abe George Tom Abe_Lose George_Lose Tom_Lose
#1    4/12   0      0   1        1           1        0
#2    4/13   1      0   0        0           1        1
#3    4/14   0      1   0        1           0        1
#4    4/15   0      0   1        1           1        0
```

**DATA**

```
str(d3)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Date  : Factor w/ 4 levels "4/12","4/13",..: 1 2 3 4
 $ Winner: Factor w/ 3 levels "Abe","George",..: 3 1 2 3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! One of the many great answers I received

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a better way than this but this works in base R and it's fairly simple:

If your data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = c("4/12","4/13","4/14","4/15"),Winner = c("Tom","Abe","George","Tom"))
```

Append the extra columns like so:

```
xcols <- c(paste0(unique(df$Winner), '_Win'), paste0(unique(df$Winner), '_Lose'))
df[ , xcols] <- 0
```

Now make a character vector with instructions to give the points for every player.

`evl <- unlist(lapply(unique(df$Winner), function(x){paste0('df[', which(df$Winner == x), ',', which(names(df) == paste0(x, '_Win')), '] <- 1')}))`

And execute the code:

```
eval(parse(text = evl))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("4/12", "4/13","4/14", "4/15"),
  Winner = c("Tom", "Abe", "George", "Tom")
)


df2 <- do.call(cbind,
      lapply(seq_along(levels(df$Winner)), function(x) {

         win  <- ifelse(df$Winner == levels(df$Winner)[x], 1, 0)
         lose <- ifelse(df$Winner == levels(df$Winner)[x], 0, 1)

         dat <- cbind(win, lose)
         colnames(dat) <-  c(paste(levels(df$Winner)[x], "win", sep = "_"),  paste(levels(df$Winner)[x], "lose", sep = "_"))

         dat
     })
)


cbind(df, df2)


> cbind(df, df2)
  Date Winner Abe_win Abe_lose George_win George_lose Tom_win Tom_lose
1 4/12    Tom       0        1          0           1       1        0
2 4/13    Abe       1        0          0           1       0        1
3 4/14 George       0        1          1           0       0        1
4 4/15    Tom       0        1          0           1       1        0
```